Upsampling parameters in the Takahashi-Alexander model
Let me start by begging your forebearance; this question might at first glance appear to belong more on a forum for economics, but I hope by the end to convince you that there is mathematical content here.
The Takahashi-Alexander model was developed to help invest illiquid asset classes and is still in use today because it easy to understand and justify. For those unfamiliar, the model has the following input parameters and outputs:
Inputs:

$RC$ - rate of contribution
$CC$ - capital commitment
$L$ - life of fund (years)
$B$ - bow factor
$G$ - annual growth rate
$Y$ - yield

Outputs:

$C$ - capital contributions
$D$ - distributions
$NAV$ - net asset value

The outputs are defined inductively as follows:
\begin{align*}
C(t) &= RC(t) \cdot \left( CC - \sum_{s=0}^{t-1} C(s) \right), C(0)=0 \\
D(t) &= RD(t) \cdot NAV(t) \cdot (1+G), D(0)=0 \\
NAV(t) &= NAV(t-1) \cdot (1+G) + C(t) - D(t), NAV(0)=0
\end{align*}
Here $RD$ denotes a rate of distribution function. It is quite common for investors to choose their own function, but the one considered in the original TA paper and the one I will refer to here is given by
$$ RD(t) = \max\left(Y, \left(\frac{t}{L} \right)^B \right).$$
It should be clear that there is no real need for the units in this model to be years; assuming all inputs adhere to the same frequency (bi-annually, quarterly etc.) the model definition still makes perfect sense.
What I am interested in is whether any work has been done on converting the input parameters from the annual model into higher frequencies (which I will refer to as "upsampling" them) to get some sort of equivalent higher-frequency model. I have not been able to find anything about this online, so I will put down my own thoughts. I would greatly appreciate either references to prior work or suggestions on how to go further.
This question will not have a unique answer so I am happy to make some additional assumptions for what a "reasonable" upsampling should satisfy. Let $f$ denote our higher frequency (the number of units per year, e.g. bi-annually $f=2$, quarterly $f=4$). I will denote the input parameters in the higher frequency with a tilde (~). One example of what a reasonable upsampling of $RC$ might satisfy is that the same rate of contribution is used for periods in the same year, and that the total contributions across the year are the same in both the annual and higher frequency model:
\begin{align*}
\tilde{RC}((m-1)f+1) = &\dots = \tilde{RC}(mf) =: \tilde{RC}_m \\
\tilde{C}((m-1)f+1) + &\dots + \tilde{C}(mf) = C(m)
\end{align*}
for $m=1,\dots, L$. With these assumptions, the unique (common) value for the higher frequency rate of contribution in year $m$ is
$$ \tilde{RC}_m = 1 - \sqrt[f]{1-\frac{RC(m)\prod_{s=1}^{m-1}(1-RC(s))}{\prod_{s=1}^{m-1}(1-\tilde{RC}_s)^f}}.$$
Of course we could make different assumptions here, such as asking that the same contributions are made in each period and not the same rate of contribution, and this would no longer be the correct upsampling. I would love to hear different suggestions of assumptions, so long as they are clear.
In terms of assumptions on $\tilde D, \tilde{NAV}$, the ones I have been working with are that the total distributions over the year are the same in either frequency and that the net asset value at the end of each year is the same in either model:
\begin{align*}
\tilde D((m-1)f+1) + &\dots + \tilde D(mf) = D(m)\\
\tilde{NAV}(mf) &= NAV(m)
\end{align*}
for $m=1,\dots, L$. I have made less progress here determining closed forms for the upsampled parameters, so I am also interested in numerical solutions if they can be shown to exist. If someone knows of a way to formulate this an optimization problem for me to solve, that would also be very helpful.
I'm sorry that this question is quite open-ended, but I already appreciate anyone who took the time to read this far, I know it is very long.
P.S. It is not too hard to find non-recursive definitions of the outputs. I am unsure if they are helpful, but I will add them here just in case:
\begin{align*}
C(m) &= RC(m) \cdot CC \cdot \prod_{s=1}^{m-1}(1-RC(s)) \\
D(m) &= RD(m) \cdot \sum_{t=1}^{m-1} \left( C(t)(1+G)^{m-t}\prod_{s=t+1}^{m-1} (1-RD(s))\right) \\
NAV(m) &= \sum_{t=1}^m \left( C(t)(1+G)^{m-t} \prod_{s=t+1}^m (1-RD(s)) \right)
\end{align*}
